# Bit length of text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit, valueconverter

How to count bits of the string in JavaScript? 
For example how many bits long is the string `0000xfe-kemZlF4IlEgljDF_4df:1102pwrq7`?

Comment: I doubt that the spec for JavaScript prescribes an internal representation of strings for a JavaScript engine. Are you asking how much memory a JavaScript string occupies? For which JS environment?

Comment: @Jacob the internal representation of javascript string is specified to be unsigned 16-bit integers http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.16

Comment: It's to implement Chrome Extension

Comment: Actually, it specifically says "Each integer value in the sequence usually represents a single 16-bit unit of UTF-16 text. However, ECMAScript does not place any restrictions or requirements on the values except that they must be 16-bit unsigned integers." You may typically encode the string as UTF-16, but that's not a requirement in the spec.

Comment: @Jacob *A conforming implementation of this Standard shall interpret characters in conformance with the Unicode Standard, Version 3.0 or later and ISO/IEC 10646-1 with either UCS-2 or UTF-16 as the adopted encoding form, implementation level 3. If the adopted ISO/IEC 10646-1 subset is not otherwise specified, it is presumed to be the BMP subset, collection 300. If the adopted encoding form is not otherwise specified, it presumed to be the UTF-16 encoding form.*

Comment: How many bits would it be the example string "0000xfe-kemZlF4IlEgljDF_4df:1102pwrq7" and to count it in JS or jQuery in Chrome?

Comment: Yep, so the number of bytes for a string could differ whether USC-2 or UTF-16 is used.

Comment: @HolySync, it's unclear what problem you're trying to solve. Are you sure you really need to know the number of bits for the string, and if so, why? If so, you should check if there is Chrome-specific documentation for their JS engine.

Comment: I need to make sure if given value is at least 128bit. 
This is a matter of security (how long will it take to guess the value with BruteForce). Hope it will clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string provided ("0000xfe-kemZlF4IlEgljDF_4df:1102pwrq7") would be:

```
length * 2 * 8
```

bits long, or **592 bits**.

This is because each char in a string is treated as a 16-bit unsigned value, at least in the most common mainstream implementation. The details of this can [probably be discussed](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding), but you mention in the comments that it is for security purposes -

So assuming you are giving ASCII characters (0-127) or UTF-8 (0-255) you can use the `TextEncoder` object to make sure you provide enough chars to produce 128 bits. Just be careful with Latin-1 chars in UTF-8 as the encoder may project them to the UTF-16 equivalent meaning it will produce 2 bytes for it instead of just one.

If you use a plain JavaScript string to hold ASCII characters you will have half the positions represented as 0's which reduce the security significantly, so an encoding from UTF-16/UCS-2 to ASCII or UTF-8 is required.

To use [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) you simply provide a string representing 16 characters, at this point 256 bits (16x16) but where each char is within the ASCII/UTF-8 value range. After encoding, unless some special chars where used, the binary buffer as typed array should represent 128 bits (16x8).

#### Example

```js
if (!("TextEncoder" in window)) alert("Sorry, no TextEncoder in this browser...");
else {
  btn.onclick = function() {
  
    var s = txt.value;
    if (s.length !== 16) {
      alert("Need 16 chars. " + (16 - s.length) + " to go...");
      return
    }
  
    var encoder = new TextEncoder("ASCII");  // or use UTF-8
    var bytes = encoder.encode(s);
  
    console.log(bytes);

    if (bytes.byteLength === 16) alert("OK, got 128 bits");
    else alert("Oops, got " + (bytes.byteLength * 8) + " bits.");
  };
}
```

```html
<label>Enter 16 ASCII chars: <input id=txt maxlength=16></label>
<button id=btn>Convert</button>
```

An alternative to `TextEncoder` if using older browsers is to manually iterate over the string and extract and mask each char to build a binary array from that.

Comment: @elad.chen thanks, I added the link to the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy the string into a buffer and then check the length of the buffer?

var str = ' ... ';

var buf = new Buffer(str);

console.log(buf.length);

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you just need to make sure the given value is at least 128 bit, then you're probably passing this string to something that will be converting the string to some byte representation. How the string is converted to bytes depends on how it's encoded.

The sample string you gave us contains ASCII-range characters. If the string is encoded as ASCII, then it's 8 bits per character. If the string was encoded as UTF-8, then it would be 8 bits per character, but if the string could contain larger character values than the sample you provided, then it may be more than 8 bits per character depending on the character. If it's encoded as UTF-16, then each character is a minimum of 16 bits, but could be more depending on the character. If it's encoded as  USC-2, then it would always be 16 bits per character.

We don't know where this requirement is coming from and how the system requiring this string uses it. If the system uses a fixed number of bits per character, then this is as straightforward as taking the `length` of the string and multiplying by the appropriate number. If it's not that straightforward, then you would need to *encode* the string using the proper encoding, most likely to a byte array, then multiply 8 * the number of bytes to get the number of bits.